# Clustering Programming Exercise Feasible or did the author forget to mention something?

Tags: java, algorithm, cluster-computing

I have been reading and working on problems from a book written by Dr. Premchand S. Nair. I just want to know if this question is feasible or did he forget to mention some details? **Not looking for anyone to solve it.** The questions is as follows:

Implement the following simple clustering algorithm. As a new point is entered by 
the user, check whether or not it lies within any cluster. If so, mark it with the  cluster number. If it does not fall in any existing cluster, start a new cluster with the new point as center and radius, r, that is specified by the user and is the same for all clusters.

That is the whole question.

Comment: It is feasible.

Comment: Seems straightforward, since each point is user defined and r is defined once for all clusters. For the first point, there are zero clusters so create one and give it a number, then continue as instructed for every other point entered.

Comment: Do I have to use an ArrayList?

Comment: From my perspective and my limited knowledge here and without having read a single line of the book you mention - it is hard to say at the moment if the question is feasible without more detail Is there a definition of 'cluster' included in the Dr. Permchand S Nair's problem? I would reckon there is an appendix or the like?

Comment: And, would you please post some code ideally using the [code] tag to format the code in a readable manner, so that someone can help you on this. There is a Documentation section in the top bar of this site where you should be able to find hints on how to include code in your posts. Great you read about clustering :-)

Comment: Nothing! Do I have to use more than one ArrayList?? No code just a question.

Comment: Do you *have* to use an ArrayList? No, but you could solve using only one ArrayList, as well as other data structures, but you might want to ask yourself if that is the most efficient way to solve the problem. The problem given in this question is fairly open to interpretation. No dimensionality, distance measure, or type of input is mentioned (i.e., are you meant to cluster 3-dimensional real-valued points using Euclidean distance?). There are countless ways to solve (and interpret) the problem.

Comment: @lucidMonkey But don't you think the problem is never ending?

Comment: It is poorly stated, vague, and open to interpretation. It is better to avoid assumptions, but there's no need to be excessively pedantic. In this case, the problem ends when you stop giving input. In machine learning, there is typically a training data set and test data set, which naturally defines when to stop feeding input. If the book in question is"Java Programming Fundamentals: Problem Solving Through Object Oriented Analysis and Design", then I take this at face value as a simple exercise to get you to use what you learned from the chapter.

Comment: I added the code in the answer section. Is it correct or a least partial correct?

Answer (score 1):

If a cluster is disjunct to any other cluster, it is not feasible.

Here is the counter-example: The point in the middle doesn't belongs to a cluster. The point can't be the middle of a new cluster.

[image]

If a cluster can overlap with an other cluster, it is feasible. But then, a point can be in multiple clusters:
[image]